# How can I store console.log response in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I have a function that returns the names and id's of my friends on facebook. I need help in storing them in an array for accessing them later. Any ideas?

```
//using JQuery 
function getFriends() {
    alert(" ok lets try and retrieve some friends ");
    FB.api('/me/friends', function (response) {
        if (response.data) {
            alert("waiting for the buddies list");
            $.each(response.data, function (index, friend) {
                console.log(friend.name + ' has id:' + friend.id);
            });
        } else {
            alert("Unable to retrieve friends' list");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Your title is a little mis-informative..

Comment: And why can't you just store a reference to `response.data`?

Comment: `console.log()` is for debugging purpose only. use `push`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
console.log(friend.name + ' has id:' + friend.id);
```

With something like this:

```
friends.push({'name' : friend.name, 'id' : friend.id});
```

Although it looks like you're basically just running through the response data and rebuilding it, perhaps tossing out some extra data from each friend?

Comment: andreas....fixed my mistake zzzBov response.data (sorry new to this gonna have to look that up ) Demnogonis- understood but I just got this function to work for me since I'm so incredibly new to it. @Cecchi the extra data? ultimately I'd like to use this array in jQuery's autocomplete widget but I need an array of my friends names...

Comment: @VanessaHernandez all I was saying was it looks like the `friends` object you are making winds up being _very_ similar to what you already have in the `response.data`. If that's the case you can just do `friends = response` and assuming friends belongs to a broader scope you can then use it elsewhere later on.